# Linked List - insert more than one node

Tags: c++, insert, linked-list, nodes

I'm new to c++ and am having a hard time understanding insertion in a linked list. Here is my insert that I've been working on so far, I'm just having trouble adding more than one node.

```
struct node *temp, *x, *y;
temp = create_node(a, b, c);
x = begin;
if (begin == NULL)
{
    begin = temp;
    temp->next = NULL;
}
else
{
    y = temp;
    temp->next = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: In C++ you can use [std::list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list)

Comment: I'm using my own. I'm just trying to figure out how to insert properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last part of your code (insertion when the list is not empty) is not adjusting correctly the pointers. The following code fixes the issue:

```
struct node *temp;
temp = create_node(a, b, c);
if (begin == NULL)
{
    begin = temp;
    temp->next = NULL;
}
else
{
    temp->next = begin;
    begin = temp;
}
```

Comment: I see what I did... Thank you

Comment: when you are dealing with this kind of operations just try to draw the nodes and pointers on a piece of paper and perform the operation on it. Normally it's easier to see what pointers you have to change.